# Mobile Webapp: render data list in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications

I am currently developing a webapp aimed for mobile devices which basically consists of a couple of long and complex lists, lots of data, collapsible cascading elements.

I'm getting the data to be displayed as XML, now as I see it I have two options:

- build the list on the server and send HTML to the client
- send XML to the client, build the list with Javascript/jQuery

Not sure which is more efficient, less data to transfer is good, less load on (especially older) phones is also good.

Any other pros/cons I'm not seeing? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The less data you send the better.

I often prefer to make a one-page application.  All of the data needed is loaded via AJAX or Web Sockets (check out Socket.IO for a nice wrapper, with compatibility for mobile browsers that don't directly support Web Sockets).  That way, you can have a much smoother user experience, and save bandwidth while doing it.

The con with this method is SEO.  Search engines won't be running your JavaScript, and therefore won't index any data you are displaying.  For "application" like sites, this is typically not a problem.  If your site is more content based, then it might be an issue for you.  There are ways around this, and progressive enhancement goes a long way to helping the problem.  You will need to decide if this is right for you and your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The presentation of Nicholas C. Zakas on velocity 2013 can help you.
[Enough with the JavaScript Already](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/enough-withthejavascriptalready). The peroformace or js rendering is very bad, especially for mobile webapp. We have changed the render of data list form js to php in some appliction. You should try to compare the performace or these two ways, and choose the better one. I recommend you do the render of big list in php, just for performce.